# C++ Input/output

Tags: c++, input, output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a , b , c , i , n;
    int d = 0;
 ifstream myfile;
 myfile.open("Duomenys1.txt");
 myfile >> n;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
 {
     myfile >> a >> b >> c;
     d +=  (a + b + c)/3 ;
 }
ofstream myotherfile;
myotherfile.open ("Rezultatai1.txt");
myotherfile << d;
myotherfile.close();
myotherfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

The programs should read 3 (3 is n) rows of numbers (5 7 4 ; 9 9 8; 8 7 8), rows are summed up separately and given 3 different averages (7 ; 9 ; 8) in the  Rezultatai1.txt file. But I only get -2143899376 result.

The problem isn't the huge number, I need the program to give every row's average number separately  in the output file, so that in the output file its written (7 ; 9 ; 8)

Comment: Is the program you show the actual program you run? Is the data you show for the input file the actual data? Then you should get `20` as result in the output file.

Comment: works fine for me (result is `5+8+7=20`). How does your input file look like? Btw, integer arithmetic gives `(9+9+8)/3=8` not `9`.

Comment: @Walter I just used the number the OP provided as the averages, though they are wrong.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg never trust the OP

Comment: For the OP, [here's your program working](http://ideone.com/joZX5a) (just changed to use `std::cin` for input and `std::cout` for output, and some minor formatting). My guess as for your problem? You forgot to initialize `d` in your actual code.

Comment: @Walter (9 + 9 + 8 )/3 = 8.666 , the results are rounded I forgot to say that

Comment: @ParanoidParrot There's no rounding in your program, you use only integer arithmetic so the results are *truncated*.

Comment: @ParanoidParrot **Nope** the results of integer arithmetic are never rounded. In C/C++ `(9+9+8)/3=8`. Even `int((9.0+9.0+8.0)/3.0)=8`, since `int(8.66666666667)=8`, i.e. no rounding when converting floating point numbers to integral numbers.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg You didn't understand what the problem(I think I wasn't clear enough), I need the program to give the average of every row separately

Comment: So the question is not about the huge engative number you get? Then I suggest you update your question to clearly stat what your *actual* problem is.

Comment: I kinda don't know how to state it otherwise then;              The programs should read 3 (3 is n) rows of numbers (5 7 4 ; 9 9 8; 8 7 8), rows are summed up separately and given 3 different averages (7 ; 9 ; 8) in the Rezultatai1.txt file

Comment: (A) The code's formatting is terrible. (B) ` d +=  (a + b + c)/3 ;` Can you not see the problem? This is cumulatively adding the average for each row, together with the others.

Answer (score 1):

You must make one output per line and you must use floating point arithmetic followed by rounding if you want rounded averages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  const int numbers_per_lines = 3;
  std::ofstream output("Rezultatai1.txt");
  std::ifstream input("Duomenys1.txt");
  int number_of_lines;
  input >> number_of_lines;
  for(int i=0; i<number_of_lines; ++i) {
    double sum=0;
    for(int num=0; num<numbers_per_line; ++num) {
      double x;
      input >> x;
      sum += x;
    }
    output << i << ' ' << std::round(sum/numbers_per_line) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems: First of all you don't do any rounding, instead since you use integer arithmetic the result is *truncated*. There are a couple of ways to do rounding, one of the simple is to use *floating point* arithmetic, and use e.g. [`std::round` (or `std::lround`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) to round to nearest integer value. Like e.g.

```
d = std::round((a + b + c) / 3.0);
```

Notice the use of the floating point literal `3.0` when dividing.

The second problem is that you don't write the averages, you sum all averages and write the sum. This can be fixed by simple write the average in the loop instead of after the loop, and use plain assignment instead of increase-and-assign.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    freopen("Duomenys1.txt", "r", stdin);    // Reopen stream with different file
    freopen("Rezultatai1.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n, a, b, c;
    cin >> n;
    while (n--) {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        cout << (a + b + c) / 3 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
3
5 7 4
9 9 8
8 7 8
```

**Output**

```
5
8
7
```

See <kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/HNvJ0W)</kbd>.